# Do I use Option as result when fetching an object from the database with an Id?

Tags: oop, scala, functional-programming, playframework-2.0, slick

I have made a definition which fetches a user from the database.

```
 def user(userId: Int) : User = database withSession {
    (for{
      u <- Users if u.id === userId} 
    yield u).first
  }
```

Potetially the database could return an empty list if used with an non existing userId.
However I can't see when a non existing userId would be provided. For example my userId is fetched from the logged in user. And if a non existing userId is provided then I think it's ok to fail the request hard.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Very similar question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886781/should-my-persistence-class-return-option-or-rely-on-exceptions

Answer (score 4):

No it's not ok to fail the request hard :

```
def user(userId: Int) : Option[User] // is OK
def user(userId: Int) : Either[String,User] // is OK
def user(usedId: Int) : User // is not OK
```

or else you could create a type (a concept) which encapsulate an Integer which make sure it's a valid UserId (at birthing).

```
sealed case class UserId(u:Int) //extends AnyVal // If it's scala 2.10.0

object UserId {
    def get(i:Int) : Option[UserId] = //some validation

} /// ....

def  user(userId:UserId) : User //is OK // well it depends on the semantic of user destruction.
```

When you make a def, you must make sure there is a proper relation between the domain (this and args) of your function and the codomain (result).

Anyways, do not hesitate to type (create concepts), it will help you to reason about your code.

---

Why `def user(userId: Int) :User` is not Ok ?

Because a relation between the elements of `Integer` to the elements of `User` doesn't exist. What if UserIds are all positive integers, but you ask for `user(-10)` ? (it won't happen, right ?) Should this call raise an exception ? Or return null ?

If you think it should return null, then return an Option, it encapsulates the potential missing correspondance.

If you think it should raise an exception, then return :

- a `Validation[SomethingRepresentingAnError, User]` (scalaz),
- an `Either[SomethingRepresentingAnError, User]` (scala 2.7, 2.8, 2.9)
- or a [`Try[User]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.Try) (scala 2.10)

Having rich return types will help you to use your API correctly.

Btw Scala doesn't use checked exception, so you cannot use exception as an alternative result. Exception should be keept for truly exceptional behaviour (as Runtime Exceptions).

See also :

- http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.control.Exception$

Comment: Care to elaborate why it's not OK? The official documentaion of SLICK uses this approach.

Comment: It's a long discussion about the fundamentals of functional programming. Types are concepts, function are relation between concepts.

It also applies to good oop programming. (I care, but I am on the go)

Comment: I'have to reserve the statement of the documentation as it was embeded in some template code.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's always good idea to return Option[] when fetching data by id. You can not be sure that user with such id exist. E. g. another request has deleted this user or somebody was trying to tamper with your input data. Database is an external system to your application and if you know how to recover from such failures then you should do it. Especially in Scala where Option is a good tool for such task.

Answer (score 1):

`Option` is the most minimalistic way to represent the return value from some computation that may fail. Throwing exceptions or returning `null` are acceptable *only* when dealing with Java code and your hands are somehow tied by an existing API (and when you're code is being called from Java code).

The next step up from `Option` would be `Either[FailureIndication, SuccessValue]`.

A further improvement is ScalaZ's `Validation`.